# Evaluating formula from csv using EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

To load formulas in a range I've used this method

```
ws1.Cells["B4:D4"].LoadFromText($"={con_Fu_LF},={con_Un_LF},={con_Fo_LF}");
```

and to evaluate I've called

```
ws1.Cells["B4:D4"].Calculate();
```

Opening the workbook I see strings in that range, for example in B4:

> ='Fu-LF'!F6841+'Fu-LF'!K6841

these are evaluated when I click on formula bar selecting a cell and press enter.

I want these to be evaluated automatically, how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LoadFromText` sets the cell `.Value` property.  But you need to set the `.Formula` like this:

```
ws.Cells["B4"].Formula = $"={con_Fu_LF}";
```

It works with the spacebar trick because that is Excel itself detecting that it "looks" like a formula and automatically setting it.

There is no way to do it that doesnt require you to loop through the cells/strings manually.

Comment: Is there any way to set formulas for a range? For example: `ws1.Cells["B4:D4"].Formula = $"={con_Fu_LF},={con_Un_LF},={con_Fo_LF}";`

Comment: @Emon no, unfortunately, I have never seen a way.  In theory the logic would be the same as `LoadFromText` so could put in a gut hub request or folk the repo and try it.